# Any idea what are these circular rock marks?

Tags: geology, rocks

During a family trip in the Israeli National Trail in the Pora Stream part ([31.496871, 34.770928](https://goo.gl/maps/AvwfEahYm3k)), I noticed these circular rock marks.

Any idea what are they?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Shalom Ahi, looks like fractures, maybe? Not sure if anthropogenic or not. Is this in a wadi? Unlikely to be fossils imo. Ask [these guys](https://www.facebook.com/groups/177317368993025/), they're usually good in Israeli geology.

Comment: They look like weak concretions, or maybe rip up clasts. you get weird lump shapes to mudstone as it breaks up becasue variation by chemistry effect strength as strongly as variation by particle size.

Comment: No scale given...

Comment: I agree with the concretion idea. Maybe someone with better understanding than I could post an answer that explains what concretions are and how they form.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisolite

Comment: By the way, the OP didn't mention it, but being familiar with the local geology it is limestone.

Comment: They look like concretions to me.  There are a lot of freshly fractured rock in the images, some people may be collecting fossils in the area which would support the concretion idea.  Some more information would help in the identification

Comment: @Friddy What kind of information will help?

Comment: For me I would want to know what the rock texture is, granular, silty, small crystals, large crystals.  Whether it is hard or soft.  Do the center of the structures appear harder or softer than the surrounding rock.  What are the fractures on the rock like, if you have some conchoidal fracture you might have a lot of silica in the rock with some chert in areas.  Just by looking at it it could be a silty limestone with silica in the mix the shapes might be associated with the deposition of the original material.

Comment: @Friddy Thanks a lot for the details. It's not on my daily commute, but when I will pay a visit when I'm near the Pora stream and take these metrics.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like onion skin weathering. It appears in places with large temperature differences between night and day and associated thermal expansion and contraction of rocks on daily basis. That creates weaker spherical zones, where cracks may form later. I have seen that several times in basalts but not limestones, though.